# Find the number of processes when forking

Tags: unix, fork, system-calls

I was reading this operating system books and they were talking about forking in UNIX machines. I understand that the `fork()` is a system call which create a copy of the process (one parent and one child). Lets say have the below code:

```
1 int main(){
2  pid = fork ();
3  if (pid !=0)
4     fork();
5  fork();
```

When the PID is 0 then we are in the child process, if not then we are in parent right? so the above code execute as follow (when in line 2):

```
    P0
    /\
   P0 P1
```

Since P1 is not 0, then we execute line 4 - then we execute line 5 which means P0 gets forked

```
    P0
  /    \
 P0     P1
 /\    /  \
P0 P2  P1 P3
```

so the total number of processes created are: P0, P1, P2, P3 , 4 processes ? the book says it is six processes but there is no indication of how this was done.

thanks

update: this is no homework question as I have stated that the result should be 6 processes, I just dont understand how the book got this answer

Comment: The code has 3 fork lines. Try marking line numbers in your drawing.

Comment: @hyde I forked that 3 times in my drawing, is that correct?

Comment: well, clearly not correct, since you end up with 4 processes in your drawing when correct result is 6 (which is indeed correct as far as I can see)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should create total 6 processes.

- Main process (say PM) will execute code from lines 1 to 5 , which include 2 forks(@line 2 and 5) hence generates two child processes say PC1 and PC2 
  {fork @line 4 will be executed only by child process not by Main process}

  Child processes created @ line 2 (say PC1) executes code from line 3 to 5, which includes 2 forks (@ line 4 and 5) hence generates two child processes say PCC1 and PCC2

  Child processes created @ line 4 (say PCC1) executes code @ line 5, which is fork hence generate one more child process say PCCC1

Total 6 processes = PM + PC1 + PC2 + PCC1 + PCC2 + PCCC1

Drawing:

```
 
        PM
      /    \
    PC1    PC2
    (@2)   (@5)
   /    \

 PCC1   PCC2
 (@4)   (@5)
  /
PCCC1
(@5)
```

*Note: Since there is only if statement (not if-else), fork @line 5 will be called by Main process and two child processes.*